# Поиск на сайте по двум параметрам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток :) 
Помогите пожалуйста с небольшой задачкой.

На сайте есть два поля input type="text". И обычная кнопка button.
При нажатии на кнопку button, нужно сделать что бы с input 1 брало тот запрос что человек ввел, с input 2 брало такое же значение, и искало совпадения в "таблице" с этими двумя значениями, и те блоки где значения совпадает, оставляло, где не совпадает, скрывало.

Все это у меня получилось сделать только с input 1, а значение с input 2 оно вообще не хочет цеплять. Не подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
    $('.search_nomer_button').click(function() { 


    _this = $('.one_nomer');
    _this_two = $('.other_nomer');

        $.each($(".bottom_line_table > div"), function() {
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();                
    };
});

            $.each($(".bottom_line_table > div"), function() {
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this_two).val().toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();                
    };
});





    });
```

Вот с этим кодом, замечательно ищет все только с первым значением. А второе как будто не видит.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, HTML. И попробуйте сделать все одним циклом. Условие *if* из второго цикла можно перенести в первый и получить такое: _if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1 || $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this_two).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)_. Это будет значить, что если найден текст из первого *или* второго input, то показать, иначе скрывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#serch').on('click',function(){
  let mainNum = $('#main_number').val();
  let othNum = $('#other_number').val();
$(".bottom_line_table > div").each(function(index,item){
  let chkMain = $(item).find('.main_number_table').text();
  let chkOther = $(item).find('.other_nuber_table').text();
  if (mainNum !== chkMain && othNum !== chkOther){
    $(item).hide();
  }
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='main_number' type="text"> 
<input id='other_number' type="text">
<button id='serch'>Hide</button>
<div class='bottom_line_table'>
  <div>
    <div calss='table_number'>
      <div class='mini_table_block'>
        <div class='main_number_table'>o7777o</div>
        <div class='other_nuber_table'>777</div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://nomera.cu11017.tmweb.ru/wp-content/themes/your-clean-template/img/rus_mini.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='region'>Москва</div>
    <div class='date_update'>19.05.2018</div>
    <div class='prod'>Руслан</div>
    <div class='price_nomer'>480 000</div> 
  </div>
    <div>
    <div calss='table_number'>
      <div class='mini_table_block'>
        <div class='main_number_table'>z2222z</div>
        <div class='other_nuber_table'>222</div>
                <div>
          <img src="http://nomera.cu11017.tmweb.ru/wp-content/themes/your-clean-template/img/rus_mini.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='region'>Москва</div>
    <div class='date_update'>19.05.2018</div>
    <div class='prod'>Руслан</div>
    <div class='price_nomer'>480 000</div> 
  </div>
    <div>
    <div calss='table_number'>
      <div class='mini_table_block'>
        <div class='main_number_table'>b11111b</div>
        <div class='other_nuber_table'>333</div>
                <div>
          <img src="http://nomera.cu11017.tmweb.ru/wp-content/themes/your-clean-template/img/rus_mini.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='region'>Москва</div>
    <div class='date_update'>19.05.2018</div>
    <div class='prod'>Руслан</div>
    <div class='price_nomer'>480 000</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, в каком направлении работать я понял, только попробовал как то применить это на сайте, но результат почему то получился не такой как у Вас... :)
Вот ссылка на сам проект http://nomera.cu11017.tmweb.ru/
Может подскажите уже видя весь код.

Comment: Вот 2 input куда нужно вводить значения http://prntscr.com/m2qb08 , а вот таблица по которой идет поиск http://prntscr.com/m2qbau

Comment: Вот так должно работать.